# unexpected 'return' using shorthand

Tags: php

```
if(isset($feed)){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```

I tried this shorthand

```
isset($feed) ? return true : false;
```

but I gotten an error, what's wrong here?

Comment: Return is a statement, not an expression keyword. It can only be the leftmost instruction. Use `return` → `isset` ? `expr` : `expr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` is a statement, not an expression.

```
return isset($feed) ? true : false;
```

Or since the ternary operator is redundant:

```
return isset($feed);
```

Comment: return isset($feed); will return 1 if I echo my function?

Comment: @ivyong `1` equals to `true` in PHP.

Comment: @budhajeewa: That's not true. You're ignoring _type_.

Comment: It will echo as "1" though. And false echoes as "".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, without checking the type.

`true == 1` is correct, but not `true === 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator is *NOT* a "shorthand" for the if/else statement suite.

At best, you could try the following:

```
isset($feed) ? return true : return false;
```

but even that is incorrect, because the result of a conditional operator must be an *expression*, not a statement. `return` has no "result".

This:

```
return (isset($feed) ? true : false);
```

or, preferably, just this:

```
return isset($feed);
```

will get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Change This:

```
isset($feed) ? return true : false;
```

to

```
return(isset($feed) ? true : false);
```

Thank about it this way: **Ternary operators always result in something that can be 'returned'.**

Or you can simply do

```
return isset($feed);
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if(isset($feed)){
  return true;
}else{
  return false;
}
```